# Map + lambda expression in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, r5rs

I think I (almost) understand how map works in Scheme, but I am having trouble understand how this code works:

```
(map (lambda (x y z) (y x z))
   (list 1 2 3 4) (list + - * /) (list 5 6 7 8))
```

What actually happens inside this procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a `map` that receives multiple lists (three in this case) and a procedure that processes them, taking one element from each at a time:

```
(map (lambda (x y z) (y x z))
     (list 1 2 3 4)
     (list + - * /)
     (list 5 6 7 8))
```

The key to understand this is what's happening in the body of the `lambda`, which gets passed one element from each list in order and then does this:

```
(y x z)
```

In other words: we're taking an element from the second list (which is a procedure) and applying it to the elements from the first and third lists. For instance, for the first three elements we'll have:

```
(+ 1 5)
```

And for the second elements:

```
(- 2 6)
```

And so on. As you know, `map` will build a new list with the result of applying the procedure to all its input lists, element-wise. In this example, the result will be:

```
'(6 -4 21 1/2)
```

Which is the same as:

```
(list (+ 1 5) (- 2 6) (* 3 7) (/ 4 8))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Is it possible to call the lambda expression directly without map?

Comment: @user16655 of course, but it'll only receive three parameters and clearly it will not return a list of elements. You should read the documentation of `map` and `lambda` to understand the difference.